# Is it possible to see revenue per Android version on AdMob?

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, analytics

I have to migrate from 2.2 to 2.3 to be able to continue publishing updates of my application with AdMob library. (As they no longer accepts APK files with standalone AdMob library)

Even though statistically devices with Android OS below 2.3 are not important in general. They may be for "my" application. So, I want to be able to estimate the revenue loss by leaving out devices below 2.3.

I tried linking analytics account with the application on AdMob site, but it doesn't let me do that (or at least I couldn't find). Is there a way to to see revenue per Android version on AdMob?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get that detailed. A simple ballpark measure is to use the Developers Console to see what percentage of your users are on pre Gingerbread devices. That is the percentage you would be losing.

It is not likely to be much, and will continue to decrease.